# dbplyr Oracle alias limit database

Tags: r, oracle, dplyr, odbc, dbplyr

After a lengthy troubleshooting process I finally got RStudio to connect to my works Oracle database using the instant client. The motivation to do this was to use dbplyr to do most of my querying. However, I am unable to send any queries through dbplyr as all the column and table names are very long and result in `ORA-00972: identifier is too long.`

### Example Error

```
 test <- tbl(con, "long_shcema_name.very_long_and_descriptive_name") %>%
   select(a_column)
```

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 42000: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00972: identifier is too long

<SQL> 'SELECT *
FROM ("long_shcema_name.very_long_and_descriptive_name") "zzz7"
WHERE (0 = 1)'
```

I thought the issue was driver related. My work uses Oracle 12.2 which has a larger cap for identifiers, but dbGetQuery works fine over instantclient

### Working example without dbplyr

```
dbGetQuery(con,'
  select "a_column"
  from 
  long_shcema_name.very_long_and_descriptive_name')
```

```
a_column
    1
    0
    2
    .
    .
    .
```

This gives me the desired results.

### Does a solution exist?

I'm a little irked. It took me almost three weeks to get the odbc connection set up with my works database using the instant client. I was able to query using RODBC and ROracle from the get go, but wanted to use dplyr. It ended up not working and I don't have a whole lot of juice left to figure out why. Any help would be immensely appreciated at this point.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the second solution works for you but you cannot use dbplyr for this? Are you able to retreive the SQL-code by piping `get_query()` at the end?

Comment: I’ve run into this before and sometimes (not always) using the [in_schema](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/in_schema.html) function works. I think for you it would be something like `tbl(con, in_schema("long_shcema_name”, “very_long_and_descriptive_name"))`

Comment: The in_schema function is working. Do you have any idea of when it doesn't work? I usually try to specify the schema in the connection string so I am wondering if some more compatibility between odbc and dbplyr could be introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely not long file names (unless your table names are longer than 30 characters, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756558/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-table-name-in-oracle)) but the use of a schema. Oracle can use double quotes to identify database, schema and table names ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471948/oracle-select-double-quotes-or-no-double-quotes)). Square brackets are sometimes used for this purpose too ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742580/what-means-square-brackets-in-oracle-sql-query)).

Take a look at the SQL that produces the error message:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ("long_schema_name.very_long_and_descriptive_name") "zzz7"
WHERE (0 = 1)
```

This is most likely being interpreted as:

- database = {default}
- schema = {empty}
- table = long_schema_name.very_long_and_descriptive_name

Instead of as:

- database = {default}
- schema = long_schema_name
- table = very_long_and_descriptive_name

As @Wil comments you can address this with the `in_schema` function. If you try:

```r
 test <- tbl(con, in_schema("long_schema_name","very_long_and_descriptive_name") %>%
   select(a_column)
```

Then `show_query(test)` should return:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ("long_schema_name"."very_long_and_descriptive_name") "zzz7"
WHERE (0 = 1)
```

Note how this differs from the first query by the addition of double quotes either side of the full stop.